# Does removing an anomaly that reduces an action point give back the lost point for that turn?

Tags: the-captain-is-dead

An anomaly yellow alert card reduced the players' available action points by 1. Once someone removes the anomaly, do they automatically get another action point, i.e. the formerly reduced point, to use that turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once the anomaly is removed the normal action limit is restored giving the player back the action they did not have.